# Bash tab complete with non-first token in command substitution $(...) throws error

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Using tab completion on the first command in `$(...)`

```
cat $(w
```

When I hit `tab` I get potential completions as usual.

```
$ cat $(w
w                   wc                  which               wicd-client         wofm2opl            wpa_supplicant
```

However, in non-first positions bash shows a strange error

```
$ cat $(which w
```

shows

```
$ cat $(which w-bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
-bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

`sh` command substitution syntax shows the same expected behavior for the first position but not subsequent positions

```
$ cat `w
w                   wc                  which               wicd-client         wofm2opl            wpa_supplicant

$ cat `which w
```

has no autocompletions at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obvious , it is looking for a closing `)` , You can't hit tab after `cat $(which w`  , because `w` has to be completed by yourself , by typing some arugment name , bash completion is not for argument completion I guess . it is for the command completion.

try this behaviour after installing this bash completion , this may complete most of the things for you.

```
    yum install bash-completion 
    source /etc/bash_completion
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to configure autocompletion to recognize this particular context?

Comment: i dont consider it all that obvious, and you dont offer much in the way of convincing me otherwise. just stating some unsubstantiated claim hardly qualifies as an answer. yes - it is obviously looking for `)`but why shouldn't better handle that context? and `bash` does complete arguments, by the way.

Comment: ok , updated the answer , the default bash completion has this problem , it doesnt offer that much. try by installing the bash completion offered by yum repo